# Google Data Studio formula for determining if a date is within daylight savings time

Tags: looker-studio, dst

I have a Google Data Studio report that reports sales on a website by day. The problem is that the Date dimension GDS is using is in UTC, and the client wants to see the report in Central Time.
During Daylight Savings Time, UTC is 5 hours ahead of CT, and the rest of the time it's 6 hours ahead.
The format of the dimension is like this: `Oct 1, 2021 5:00:00 PM`
I can add/subtract hours from this format, no problem. What I need to do is subtract hours from this value conditionally based on whether the date is during Daylight Savings Time.
For instance, `Oct 1, 2021 5:00:00 PM` would become `Oct 1, 2021 11:00:00 AM` because it's not during Daylight Savings Time.
Whereas, `Nov 1, 2021 5:00:00 PM` would become `Nov 1, 2021 12:00:00 PM` since it is during Daylight Savings Time.

I've played around with an IF formula using the `MONTH`, `DAY`, and `WEEKDAY` functions, but haven't gotten any results.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: My end goal is to create formula/expression that will look at the date and return a TRUE/FALSE based on whether or not it is in DST.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are familiar with month, day function with your field, you have to know when Daylight Savings Time starts and ends. I think the starting and ending day depens of the country. Then, you need to extract the 'DayOfTheYear' from your Date field to check the condition you need. ([Take a look here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9702570?hl=en))

At the end, the formula should be something like this:

```
CASE
WHEN 'YourField_DayOfTheYear' < 'Daylight_Savings_Time_Start' AND 'YourField_DayOfTheYear' > 'Daylight_Savings_Time_End' THEN 'YourDateField' + 6 hours
ELSE 'YourDateField' + 5 hours
END
```